# Lynda or Treehouse?

Tags: java

I am thinking about joining either Lynda or Treehouse to sharpen my coding skills.  I was wondering (since they're both paid services) if anyone has any feedback or experience with either of the two.  I am also open to new suggestions, too.

thanks

Comment: How can feedback and experience be anything but subjective? He is asking for opinions and it gets locked because it is opinion-based!

Comment: Exactly what I am thinking. Lynda is great, I trust Lynda.

Comment: @r.j l, I don't understand why people at SO close such questions. Come on, they are also a source of knowledge. and in fact this is a great question up there. Please let StackOverflow GROW! Thanks!

Comment: I'll add my voice to what's been said above; IMHO there is WAY too much closure on this basis. StackOverflow is nowhere near as bad as its sister site Photography, which is rendered almost useless by this type of closure (one of the reasons that I rarely go there) but I think that as long as the answers cite reasons and examples (as opposed to "X rocks" or "Y blows" there is nothing to lose and plenty to gain by these types of  questions and the answers that they generate. (I know, I know, this should be a meta discussion...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use as many freely available resources as possible first. Here is a list of free books.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

Also Coursera and other MOOC's can be a great resource.

Personally I've used Treehouse and it helped me somewhat but is too expensive in my opinion.